# Remote desktop With client on Red Hat and Server Vista Business Edition

Tags: windows-vista, remote-desktop, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm trying to configure my vista machine to run the Remote Desktop Server yet i'm having problems. I have configured it using the following [instructions](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/turn-on-remote-desktop-in-windows-vista/). Yet it doesn't work. I have disabled the firewall and antivirus software but to no avail. I know the client is set up properly as i can log in to my friend's Remote Desktop server. The client i am using is rdesktop. What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use protocol level 4, not the default protocol level 5.

Thus, the command should be:

> rdesktop -4 [other params]

Comment: The client works its the server that is the issue, I know this as I can log in to my friends machine(he is running XP). I will however try it tomorrow when I get in.

Comment: @Dean: XP does not require this parameter, only Vista does.

Comment: @harrymc Still no success with adding it as a parameter.

Comment: @Dean: I understand you are having problems using rdesktop on Redhat to connect to Vista. I understand you can rdesktop to an XP machine. Correct me if I'm wrong. Which version of rdesktop? Vista 32-bits?

Comment: @Dean: rdesktop needs to be at least version 1.5.0 to connect to Vista.

Comment: Its the latest version of rdesktop 1.6.0. Yes you are correct with what you are thinking. I'm unsure on the version of vista as regards to 32/64 i'm thinking 32 but will check tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

If your server is behind a router (i.e., if you are trying to make this connection over the internet, not locally), you will need to forward port 3389 TCP to the server.

If you are unsure how to do that with your model of router, check out http://portforward.com/

For example, [this](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Linksys/WRT54G/Remote_Desktop.htm) is how you configure a Linksys WRT54G (a quite common and popular router) to forward that port.

Comment: Nope is not an issue as its internally before it reaches the router.